# How to use proxy in webkit webbrowser

Tags: webkit

I have application i use to connect to internet using proxy and i use for that webkit webbrowser . The problem is that webkit webbrowser do not accept proxy.
So how i can make webkit webbrowser to use proxy like the ordinary webbrowser that came with vs 2012 ?
Any help will be appreciated.